# Calculate percentage based on the sum value in the django view

Tags: python, django

I would like to display the percentage mark instead of the total sum of the mark. Right now i have a table that display the student name and their mark attendance. I would like to convert the mark attendance into a percentage. the current implementation is:

Student Name    Attendance

Annie   200

Anny 150

But i would like to show the attendance in percentange. for example:
Student Name    Attendance

Annie   100%

Anny     85%

i am not sure how to implement the method. But i have tried this:

```py
# models.py: 

class MarkAtt(models.Model):
    studName = models.ForeignKey(
        Namelist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None,
    )
    classGrp = models.ForeignKey(GroupInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
    week = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=100) #1 is present

    def get_percentage(self):
        ttlCount = MarkAtt.objects.filter(studName).count()
        perc = ttlCount / 1100 *100
        return perc



# views.py:

def attStudName(request):

    students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))
    context = {'students' : students}
    return render(request,'show-name.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have your numerator but you need your denomenator.  I'm not exactly sure what your denomenator should be with your current setup but creating a new field that uses "Count" rather than "Sum" might do the trick for you.  Then you would divid the sum field by the count field.  I would probably just do this in the view and not mess with the model.

Comment: my denominator should be fixed value of 1100. I would need to sum up their mark attendance for 11 weeks. so if their attendance is 1100/1100 then they will get 100%. otherwise, lesser percentage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatting mini-language to express a percentage in a string

```
>>> attendence = 20
>>> total = 100
>>> '{:%}'.format(attendence/total)
'20%'
```

Bear in mind this will return the answer as string instead of an `int` or `float`

To use this in your `get_percentage`, there are a few issues that will need to be addressed:

- `studName` is not defined or passed into the method but is used in the filter query. This will cause a `NameError`.
- Your filter query looks like it is just counting the students in the filter query instead of summing the attendance. You should use a `sum` annotation like you have done in the view.
- You will need to be able to get the value for 100% attendance to be able to divide by it.

To modify your implimentatiom of this on the model you could do something like this.

```py
    def get_percentage(self):
        student = MarkAtt.objects.filter(studName=self.studName).annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'))
        return '{:%}'.format(student.mark / 1100)
```

However, I don't think the `MarkAtt` model is the right place to do this as many `MarkAtt` objects could relate to one `NameList` object resulting in possibly running the same query several times for each student. I think it would be better to do this on `NameList` or the view itself.

```py
class NameList(models.Model):

    ...

    def get_percentage(self):
        attendance = self.markatt_set().annotate(total=Sum('attendance'))
        return '{:%}'.format(attendance.total / 1100)
```

Comment: i tried to use the sum annotation just like my view but there is an error. It says the queryset is not int.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to get the sum from the queryset. You need get the attribute from the queryset rather than the queryset itself. This is documented pretty well in the official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: How do i display the result in the template then ? have yet to try this code